# MongoDb unable to insert documents using Java Driver in sharded env

Tags: mongodb

When i try to connect to mongo db sharded at key "State" via jdbc, and insert document, it says missing shardKey

My all shards (2 no, all part of individual replica sets) and config servers (1 no, part of a replica set)are up and running, and i can insert document using mongos terminal, but cant insert documents using Java Driver. The mongodb version is 2.6.5.

```java
package dao;

import util.InstanceFactory;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MongoConnector {

private static MongoConnector mongoConnectorInstance;

private DB DbConnection;

public static DB getConnection(String dbName) {

  MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance = InstanceFactory.instantiateAsSingleton(MongoConnector.class);

  if (MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance.DbConnection == null) {

    synchronized (MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance) {

      if (MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance.DbConnection == null) {
        MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance.DbConnection = MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance
.getDbConnection(dbName);
      }
    }
  }

  return MongoConnector.mongoConnectorInstance.DbConnection;

}

private DB getDbConnection(String dbName) {

  DB db = null;

  try {

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("some ip address of mongos", 27017);

   // Now connect to your databases
   db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);

   System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
  }

  return db;
  }
}
```

Now when I try to insert a document using my other class with below function I get `shard key not present  code  61`

```java
 public static boolean insert(DBObject object, String table) {
    boolean status = false;
    if (object != null) {
        try {
            DB db = MongoConnector.getConnection("somedb");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(table);
            //System.out.println(collection);
            if (collection == null) {
                db.createCollection(table, null);
            }
            collection.insert(object);
            status = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MongoDao.logger.error("Could not insert in database" + e);
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

My object that is about to be inserted looks like

```java
DBobject o=new BasicDBObject("SomeColumn":"somevalue")
           .append("shardKey":"UP");
MongoDAO.insert(o,"sometable");
```

Am I missing some configuartion to connect to my shards?

Comment: I have not yet analyze in detail your Java issue, but I see your sharding key being "state": what is the cardinality of this value? and also can you confirm that you do not update the value of this attribute. When you select a sharding key you need to be sure that it has a high cardinality (to be able to distribute the values on many shards, except if you really want to target specific shards), and the sharing key is immutable. see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/

Comment: For one document, State will be one only. BUt total possible states are 36. LIke a person belongs to an state. Again, we need not to update this value ever.

Comment: @Markus: Thanks for updating formatting of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shard key is `state`, then the problem is with the construction of the document:

```
DBobject o = new BasicDBObject("SomeColumn" : "somevalue")
    .append("shardKey" : "UP");
```

It should look like

```
DBobject o = new BasicDBObject("SomeColumn" : "somevalue")
    .append("State" : "UP");
```

It looks like you did not set the shard key correctly.

Also, a couple of other notes about your sharding setup:

1. You said you have 1 config server. Use 3. Do not use 1 config server, ever, except for small test deployments that you don't care about at all. Use 3 config servers.
2. You said your shard key has 36 possible values. This is likely too few. With 36 possible values, you can have at most 36 possible chunks distributed between the shards. A small number of potential chunks will make it hard or impossible for MongoDB to balance the amount of data between the shards. You need to reconsider your shard key. Choosing a shard key is a critical part of scaling a MongoDB deployment and making the right choice requires a lot of knowledge about the system's use case; you can start with [some advice on choosing shard keys](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) from the manual.

Comment: I meant 1 config server, being part of a replica set, i.e 3 config servers actualy. Thanks anyways. On sharding issue, can it be like One State document go in one shard. As for one State there may go number of documents from 1 million to 5million. In that case will Mongo be able to balance the no of documents to two different shards?

Comment: Nope. If all documents have the same value for the shard key, they will be in the same chunk on the same shard.